# Ajax post request in Laravel, returns html

Tags: laravel

I have a problem making ajax post request in Laravel.
I followed this tutorial then I was able to make get request but not post request. 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-ajax-get-and-post-examples

When I try post request, I just get entire html back.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please show how you have implemented your code

Comment: Please show your codes

Comment: Show us the code man

Comment: @Jin, [here](https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-55-jquery-ajax-request-example-from-scratch) you can see creating example ajax request in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

The more code you describe here will get more solution.

> You may have any error in your code so it is giving the error.
>   the error is not handled so it is giving html in response. if you want to check the error you can get the response html and parse it (https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer)